# Why has my avatar become green?

Tags: support, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gravatar change?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/gravatar-change)

My avatar has changed: it was red and now it is green. Why is that ? (I'm just curious and definitely not complaining: I prefer the new avatar with its  pleasantly soothing green.)

Comment: Did you change the email address in your profile? [This thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255/gravatar-change) may provide further information and maybe even an explanation.

Comment: I voted to close this question, as it seems to be an exact duplicate of the thread I linked to above.

Comment: Ah, yes, I changed my email address, and that changed my colour. By the way, in the unlikely case that I wanted to upload my own avatar, is there a link explaining how to do that? I would have asked this as a meta question but I have become wary now and feel that it might again be an "exact duplicate" .

Comment: The avatars are handled by [gravatar.com](http://gravatar.com/). I never used that site, but it looks self-explanatory. In the unlikely case that you mention you need to make sure that the email address you use here is the same as the one registered by gravatar. Indeed, your follow-up would probably closed as a duplicate because of [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/image-upload-help-needed) that may be more helpful than the last one I pointed out to you.

Comment: To be a bit more explicit: The email address you enter in your [user profile (click here for direct access)](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/edit/3217) must match the one you registered at [gravatar.com](http://gravatar.com/). Each time your avatar is displayed, math.SE sends a query to gravatar.com containing a hash (encoded version) of your address. Gravatar then sends back the picture you uploaded there, which is then displayed here. This is maybe not 100% accurate technically, but it explains that you need not fear about revealing your email address: it's never sent in plain text.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Theo. (We seem to meet a lot on this site and as far as I am concerned, I'm delighted. Judging from your reputation, the feeling is widespread...)

Comment: Dear Georges, the feelings are mutual. Thank you very much for your kind words. I'm looking forward to our next virtual encounter.